# Getting error on Activity resume

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I got this error, when I was developing my app. When I start app on my phone, it crashes.

Something is wrong in onResume.  I can't get it, what's the problem?

Android Studio is showing line with this:

My Run Log:

```
04-15 21:49:17.624 12927-12927/com.developerfromjokela.edison E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.developerfromjokela.edison, PID: 12927
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.developerfromjokela.edison/com.developerfromjokela.edison.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3582)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2863)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
    at com.developerfromjokela.edison.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:132)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3557)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2863) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1590) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6499) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My MainActivity:

```
    package com.developerfromjokela.edison;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import java.io.File;



    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private WebView mWebView;


    String newUA;
    String oldUA;

    public MainActivity() {
        oldUA = System.getProperty("http.agent");
        newUA = "Mozilla/7.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) 
    Gecko/20170101 Firefox/7.0";
    }


    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            ((WebView) 
        findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        if (AppStatus.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isOnline()) {

            mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

            mWebView.loadUrl("https://edison.fi");


            mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


            });



            // Enable Javascript
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.nointernetmessage , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebView.saveState(outState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mAction = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        switch (mAction) {
            case "owilma":
                openservwilma();
                break;
            case "odocs":
                opengdocs();
                break;
            case "odrive":
                opengdrive();

                break;
            case "oclassroom":
                opengclassroom();
                break;
        } {

        }

    }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
                finish();
            }
        }
    public static void clearWebViewCachesCustom(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        String dataDir = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
        new File(dataDir + "/app_webview/").delete();

    }

    public void openservwilma() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://app.edison.fi/sso/wilma/login/3");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    public void navtoback() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://edison.fi");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    public void opengdocs() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void opengslides() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/presentation/u/0/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void opengdrive() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void opengclassroom() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://classroom.google.com/u/0/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void opengcalendar() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/0/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    public void openghangouts() {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.talk");
        if (intent != null) {
            // We found the activity now start the activity
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + "com.google.android.talk"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    public void openmoffice() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(oldUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.office.com/?auth=2&home=1");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
    public void openmword() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx?auth=2");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
    public void openmoutlook() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://outlook.office365.com/owa/");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }
    public void openaboutscreen() {
        Intent OpenAbout = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(OpenAbout);
    }
    public void openssanopmapro() {

        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUA);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://oppimisymparisto.sanomapro.fi/d2l/lp/auth/saml/login?target=https://oppimisymparisto.sanomapro.fi/d2l/home/36515");
        ProgressBar progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.backtodesktop){
            navtoback();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.opendocs) {
            opengdocs();

        } else if (id == R.id.openslides) {
            opengslides();
        } else if (id == R.id.opendrive) {
            opengdrive();
        } else if (id == R.id.openclassroom) {
            opengclassroom();
        } else if (id == R.id.opencalendar) {
            opengcalendar();
        } else if (id == R.id.openhangouts) {
            openghangouts();
        } else if (id == R.id.openoffice) {
            openmoffice();
        } else if (id == R.id.openword) {
            openmword();
        } else if (id == R.id.openoutlook) {
            openmoutlook();
        } else if (id == R.id.openwilma) {
            openservwilma();
        } else if (id == R.id.about_app) {
        openaboutscreen();
        } else if (id == R.id.opensanomapro) {
        openssanopmapro();

       }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
   }
```

Comment: read this line you don't have to come to stackoverflow to solve this problem  

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference

Comment: That's a lot of code for folks to wade through. Can you cut down the code so as to present a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

May be your intent is null or intent doesn't have that string.

Before calling `String mAction = intent.getStringExtra("action");` check `if(intent != null && intent.hasString("action")`

It will check where your intent is not null and intent has that string.

Answer (score 0):

change the code at onResume() method portion:

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(getIntent()!=null){
       Intent intent = getIntent();
        String mAction = intent.getStringExtra("action");
        switch (mAction) {
            case "owilma":
                openservwilma();
                break;
            case "odocs":
                opengdocs();
                break;
            case "odrive":
                opengdrive();

                break;
            case "oclassroom":
                opengclassroom();
                break;
        }
}
}
```